# How to update the feed check frequency with Google Reader?

Tags: google-reader

Is there a way to increase the frequency at which Google Reader will check feeds for updates?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't found it, but if you have a certain feed that you want updated, you can click on the "refresh" button on top of the list while that feed is "active". That will not only update the GUI, but actually force the Google server to fetch the feed again (if it's more than a certain number of minutes since the last refresh).

Feeds with only one subscriber get updated every 3 hours, and all others are updated every hour.

Comment: You can also force a refresh of all your feeds by just clicking on the 'Subscriptions' header in the left hand navigation. You should see a loading image and it say "refreshing..." to the right of the header.

Comment: @kchau While it's says refreshing the google servers will not actually connect to all your feeds to check for updates if you click the subscriptions header, it will only show you new content if it allreay is on googles servers.